# TLS 1.0 Disablement/ Inbound API integrations

Tags: integration, tls, inboundservices

We are preparing for the TLS1.0 disablement, and part of the checklist is to test any inbound API integrations.  I’m not aware of what inbound API integrations we’re using, if any.  Is there any way to check to see if any applications have connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should probably already know. However, for sake of argument, if you didn't know, you could always run the [API Usage Last 7 Days](https://login.salesforce.com/00O?rt=104&retURL=%2F00O&c=UN&c=FULL_NAME&c=EM&c=CID&c=TS&c=CC&duel0=FULL_NAME%2CUN%2CEM&scope=organization&details=yes) report (note: if this link doesn't work, go to Reports > Administrative Reports > API Usage Last 7 Days). You'll get a list of login types that are being used, as noted in the Client Id column. **Most** developers are responsible enough to use a Client Id to identify what the integration is, but if you're **still** not sure, just enable the TLS [Critical Update](https://login.salesforce.com/ruac/ruacPage.apexp?setupid=CriticalUpdates) (Setup > Build > Critical Updates), and see if anyone complains about error messages.